# fastLinkを用いたProbabilistic data Linkageについて

Tags: r

fastLinkパッケージを用いて、二つのデータセットのリンクを試みています。リンクに用いる項目日付、時間、年齢、性別で全て数値に変換しています（時間:2/11→0211、11:15→1115、男性矢印、以下のようなスクリプトを作りました。

```
result <- fastLink(dfA = data_2, dfB = data_1, varnames = c("date", "time", "age", "gend"), numeric.match = c("date", "time", "age", "gend"), cut.a.num = 1, cut.p.num = 2.5, dedupe.matches=TRUE, threshold.match =0.0001, return.all=TRUE)
```

threshold.matchはいくつか試して、0.0001より上げていくとデータ数が減っていったのでこの値にしてています。

質問は、このthreshold.matchの設定はこれで良いか？またスクリプト内に入れるべき項目が抜けていないか？の2点です。

よろしくお願いします。